# long single latch wait in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

I would like to share my problem related to page latch in SQL Server, that I don't know what the root cause is, and how to deal with it.

According to my experience, the page latch's wait time is normally high when many processes are accessing the same page; more specifically when it happens we might see many sessions captured from sp_whoisactive

The situation I am having is different; sp_whoisactive only captured 1 process that has been waiting for 30 seconds on PAGELATCH_EX on page xyz, not blocked by any session, and also not seeing other processes involved in this latch. It appears that only one session waits on this page for latch. so I don't know which session/process holds the incompatible latch on this xyz page.

Which info/metrics should I need to capture to trace this issue? Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Do sys.dm_exec_requests or sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks for that session shed any light on the situation?

Comment: @BenThul nope, it just showed the pageID that session wait on, nothing more.

Comment: Rats! Out of curiosity, what is the identifier for the page under contention? Wondering out loud if it happens to be a "special" page.

Comment: @BenThul that's just a data page of clustered index